# Do actions on database object in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates

Sorry for newbie question, but i'm not very familiar yet with Django.

What will be the best solution for this situation?

Let's say i have model class like this:

```
class ExampleItem(models.Model)
    name = models.TextField()
    ...
    #etc...
```

and a profile model which is linked to Auth.User

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    example_items = models.ManyToManyField(ExampleItem, related_name="items")
```

I have a example_item_details View, which passes ExampleItem data to template.

```
def example_item_details(request, id):
    example_item = get_object_or_404(ExampleItem, id=id)
    return render(request,
        'website/example_item_details.html',
        {'example_item': example_item})
```

in template i have a code which checks if example_item is added to manytomanyfield of profile example_items field.

In my template i have this code:

```
{% if request.user|check_if_item_is_user:example_item %}
<div class="button">
  Already Added
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="button">
  Add Item to your account
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I want to add "example_item" to "request.user.profile.example_items" on click on "Add Item to your account" 
or delete "example_item" from "request.user.profile.example_items" on click on "Already Item button" 
and reload page.

How can i do that without form?

Comment: Using a form is probably the correct approach, otherwise you'll want to look into making an ajax request.